# Removing auto-generated <a>s in the mobile menu from Divi (WP Theme)

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, divi

I am having an issue trying to *remove some auto-generated anchor tags in a mobile menu* for a customer's website. For the time being I have them "covered up" and "hidden" with CSS, but this is an obtuse solution and I'd like something eventually more refined. I am using the Divi Theme in Wordpress.

Images of the issue are shown below:

[image: An auto-generated anchor tag by The Divi theme of Wordpress]

[image: Another auto-generated anchor tag by The Divi theme of Wordpress]

This is an issue because I'd like just one row for the social links and another for the call now button to give it a nice smooth look (container div has CSS property x-overflow:auto; and child elements (container_div li a) have CSS property display:inline; and then finally the call now button is set to display:block; to put it on the next line). It's obvious to see that these mystery anchor elements are forcing everything out of alignment. Those menu items are just built from a Custom Link in Appearance > Menus in the WP admin UI.

[image: Image showing the menu created in the Wordpress Appearance > Menus interface as a custom link]

It's pretty clear that I don't have empty anchor tags in my code (which I will post at the bottom).

**What I've Tried**

*Javascript*

This type of script:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
//script here
var menuButton = document.getElementById("strategos-menu-button");
//call function here, see below

function removeEmptyAnchorsFromDiviMobile(){
    var strategosFirst = document.getElementById("menu-item-528"); //CSS ID generated by Divi for the 
    menu's 'li a'

    var strategosSecond = document.getElementById("row-cta-strategos"); //CSS ID of my own making

    strategosFirst.removeChild(strategosFirst.childNodes[0]);
    strategosFirst.removeChild(strategosSecond.childNodes[0]);
}
</script>
```

With two ways to call the function:

```
var menuButton = document.getElementById("strategos-menu-button");
menuButton.addEventListener("click", removeEmptyAnchorsFromDiviMobile);
//where 'menuButton' is the "hamburger icon" from the mobile menu module pre-built into the Divi 
theme with a CSS ID assigned to it within the page builder's interface
```

and

```
window.onload = removeEmptyAnchorsFromDiviMobile;
//where this object.onload has been placed either directly on the page in a couple different places 
or in the <head>
```

Neither approach has worked.

Next (actually first), I tried some CSS.

*CSS*

```
#menu-item-528::after{
    content:none !important;
    /*also tried*/
    display:none !important;
}
```

Did the same for the  following #row-cta-strategos, but neither approach worked.

*PHP*

TBH I have not tried anything in my child theme's file structure yet as I am not really familiar with the WP file structure and have more pressing matters at hand than spending hours in it for this small issue... so if the solution lies in modifying some function in the file structure that would be much appreciated before I spend a few hours digging through the files in my free time :)

As promised, here is the HTML for the menu. Thank you!

```
<div class="row-cta-strategos">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mycustomer" target="_blank" id= "strategos- facebook" class="header-social-call" rel="opener"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>

    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/mycustomer/about/" target="_blank" id="strategos-linkedin" class="header-social-call" rel="opener"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>

    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/companystring" target="_blank" id ="strategos-youtube" class="header-social-call" rel="opener"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>

    <a href="tel:+15555551234" class="header-social-call" id="call-strategos"><i class="fas fa-phone-square-alt"></i>
    <span id="header-call-txt-strategos">Call Now: (555) 555-1234</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably there is a problem coming from the menu. Can I get your website address?

Comment: staging2.acsntx.com

Comment: Can you remove the div and check if something has changed?

Comment: I ran it with just the <a>s and no container <div>. It removed one of the <a>s but the other is still there. I think this is good enough for now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly ***when*** to call the function below... It can be `onload` of a little after with a `setTimeout()`... On a `setInterval()` maybe?.

```
function removeEmptyAnchorsFromDiviMobile(){

  // Get ALL anchors in page
  let allAnchors = document.QuerySelectorAll("a")

  // Loop them
  allAnchors.forEach(function(anchor){

    // If the anchor has no child
    if(!anchor.hasChildNodes()){
      anchor.remove()
    }
  })

}
```

Comment: Thanks Louys for the great recommendation, but that script did not work either :/